# Same local ports and remote ports with Xming

Tags: port, x-server, xming, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I run some X11 GUI apps (e.g. Xeyes, Xcalc, Xclock) in **Windows Subsystem** with [Xming](https://sourceforge.net/projects/xming/files/) as Xserver.

[image: x11-apps]

By analyzing the ports with [TCPView](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/tcpview), I find that local ports of X11 apps (Xclient) and remote ports of Xming (Xserver) are same. Both running on same localhost IP. Here is the screenshot that shows same ports with same colored check mark.

[image: TCPView_Xming]

Question:: Why these ports number match between client and server side? Is there one type of network loop between Xserver and X apps?

Comment: I am not sure but it looks like as because Xming is running on localhost and the application on Xming is also running on localhost (it IS as you noted a subsystem)  that it has to match the ports. It would be different if you would run apps through Xming from a REMOTE server. Just a thought while looking at it.

Comment: As said in my comment, I do NOT have any confirmation about this so I think of it more as a thoughtful comment (also known as a guess) and not as an answer - as for me an answer will have a background which will be backed up by knowledge/experience and/or able to be confirmed by documentation.